# Distinct not working MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this weird behaviour in a basic query.

Think of this as a twitter feed, I'm trying to get the last action from ten different people that a user follows.

```
select DISTINCT performed_by_user_id, action_id from z_follows, actions 
WHERE user_id_following = 1 and z_follows.follower_id = actions.performed_by_user_id 
ORDER BY action_id DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

This however returns the following (with performed clearly not distinct):

[image]

I've also tried group by but it also returns unwanted data because of the order by.
Why?

**I cannot use GROUP BY because it returns incorrect data because of the ORDER BY.**

At the moment the query return this:

[image]

But I want to get only one action per user and as you can see with the screenshot above, I should see the following user id in my result 2, 236, 685 but this query:

```
select performed_by_user_id, action_id from z_follows, actions 
WHERE user_id_following = 1 and z_follows.follower_id = actions.performed_by_user_id 
GROUP BY performed_by_user_id
ORDER BY action_id DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Returns this:

[image]

Comment: The distinct applies to the resultset not to the individual columns.

Comment: You're looking for a group by.

Comment: @rlanvin group by also returns incorrect data because of the order by

Comment: @Callombert in this case you'll have to edit your question further to provide a sample of the resultset you are expecting. It looks to me that you need group by and max() and possibly a join.

Comment: Thanks, I've added things @rlanvin

Answer (score 0):

The select distinct gives you distinct rows.  If you were looking for just one of each performed_by_user_id you would use a group by.

Comment: See edited question

Comment: Can you provide an example where you use the group by?  What data are you trying to get by this query, the number of times a performed_by_user_id is selected?

Comment: I've edited the question This is the query select performed_by_user_id, action_id from z_follows, actions 
WHERE user_id_following = 1 and z_follows.follower_id = actions.performed_by_user_id 
GROUP BY performed_by_user_id
ORDER BY action_id DESC 
LIMIT 10

Comment: When you do a group by it takes the action_ids and selects one of them from the group, usually the last one but not always.  So what you are seeing is not incorrect data but the data being rearranged due to the highest action_id is at the top.  If you took the limit 10 off and sorted the data by the performed_by_user_id you would see the lower performed_by_user_id you saw in the other data set. Are you trying to get the last action_id from each performed_by_user_id?

Comment: Yeah basically I've got a twitter like feed and when a user does multiple actions, it crowds so I'm trying to switch so it shows the latest action from x user rather than the last 10 actions which sometimes show 10 actions from the same user.